# Using Ruby symbols as options

Tags: ruby, symbols

I want to know how to use Ruby symbols (e.g. `:foo`) as options in functions (and not as an option hash).

Example:

```
round(28.53, :floor)
get_data(:age)
```

How would I create a function that would accept such arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on how you expect to handle multiple options, but here is an example, based on your `round`:

```
def round( number, *opts )
  if opts.include?( :convert )
    number = number.to_f
  end

  if opts.include?( :floor )
    return number.floor
  elsif opts.include?( :ceil )
    return number.ceil      
  else
    return number.round
  end
end

round( 7.3 )
# => 7

round( 7.3, :floor )
# => 7

round( 7.3, :ceil )
# => 8

round( '7.3', :ceil )
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `ceil' for "7.3":String

round( '7.3', :ceil, :convert )
# => 8
```

The `*` construct allows you accept an array of params at the end, and you can use that to pass in multiple options. That may not make sense if they are mutually exclusive (as is the case with some of the options in the contrived example), but there is no one method signature that will cover all possible use cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to handle variable number of arguments, it works like any other argument:

```
def round(number, rounds)
  case rounds
  when :floor
    number.floor
  when :ceil
    number.ceil
  when :round
    number.round
  else
    raise ArgumentError, "unknown rounding mode: #{rounds.inspect}"
  end
end

round(28.53, :floor) #=> 28
round(28.53, :ceil)  #=> 29
round(28.53, :round) #=> 29
round(28.53, :foo)   #=> ArgumentError: unknown rounding mode: :foo
```

Comment: I would give the definition a default: `round(number, rounds = :round)`

Answer (score 0):

Is it a problem?

```
def puts_class param
  puts param.class
end

puts_class :asd

=>
Symbol
```

Actually, symbols never assumed as options in Ruby methods. It's about hashes:

```
some_method(1,2, param: :value, param2: value2) # curly braces omitted
# equal to
some_method(1,2, {param: value, param2: value2})
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to send multiple options to your method. And you want to do something if an option exists (in this case let us print it) otherwise do nothing/don't bother

```
def meth( opt = {} )
  opt.keys.each { |o| puts opt[0]
end

# pass two options 
meth(:name => 'Ruby', :floor => 23.5) #=> Ruby, 23.5

#pass one option
meth(:name => 'Rails') #=> Rails
```